# How to get field from id in AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, json, autocompletetextview

I want to get field name from id in autocomplete textview, I tried a lot but the id is not getting proper some other id is displaying.

Here some code of particular class:

```
public void getStoreData(){

    final Call<CityModel> cityModelCall = APIClient.getApiClient().city("token");
    cityModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<CityModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CityModel> call, Response<CityModel> response) {

            Log.d("Async Data RemoteData",
                    "Got REMOTE DATA "+response.body().getCityList().size());

            List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
            CityModel model = response.body();

            for(CityModel.City s : response.body().getCityList()){
                str.add(s.getCityName());
            }



            ArrayAdapter<String> adapteo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, str.toArray(new String[0]));
            mBinding.acity.setAdapter(adapteo);



        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CityModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

The above code is for getting the list of the city and set text in the autocompletetextview.

Here the model class of City.

```
public static class City{
    @SerializedName("id")
    String id;
    @SerializedName("cityName")
    String cityName;
    public  City(String id,String cityName){
        this.id = id;
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your id from Autocomplete and id from city list are not the same. Why don't you create the adapter of City object?

Comment: i tried it to but not getting the result will you please show me the example of it so that i can refer